# Flow & Record updated to meet to meet condition requirements problem

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that is set up to create Assets.  It is set up to run on Actions and Related Records.  In the decision logic, I'm checking a few values:
[image]
Either the flow will fire off when the user clicks a checkbox (Assets: Create?) or the Probability becomes 100.

The problem is that this condition is not being met ever.  When I tried to debug it, I got the following outcome:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

(Note - I moved this check into a decision from entry criteria so I could debug it easier as it wasn't working in Entry criteria also).

Answer (score 2):

I see you have the [When to Execute Outcome](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_decision.htm&type=5) set to `Only if the record that triggered the flow to run is updated to meeting the condition requirements`. My guess is that the record edit you are making to debug this is not turning this statement from 'false' to 'true'. I believe in order to do so you'd need `Assets_Create__c == TRUE` AND `Probability == 100` to both evaluate to 'false' on the prior record. Otherwise the statement is already true on the prior record, and so the decision is skipped no matter whether it evaluates to true now or not.

So if you set the record to have `Assets_Create__c == false` **AND** `Probability != 100` and save it, then when you make one of those statements truthy on your next edit the decision should fire.